# ASP.NET MVC4 WebAPI and Posting XML data

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm missing a trick with the new webapi - I'm trying to submit an xml string through a post request and not having much luck.

The front end is using jQuery like this:

```
    $(document = function () {
    $("#buttonTestAPI").click(function () {

        var d = " <customer><customer_id>1234</customer_id></customer>";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "text/xml",
            url: "@Url.Content("~/api/Customer/")",
            data: d,
            success: function (result) {
                var str = result;
                $("#output").html(str);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My controller is pretty simple at the moment - just the default for the post action - trying to return what was passed in:

```
    public string Post(string value)
    {
        return value;
    }
```

However, "value" is repeatedly null. The odd thing is, when I change my data in the jquery to be something like this:

```
d = "<customer_id>1234</customer_id>";
```

Then I get "value" in my controller as 1234.

How can I get access to the more complex xml string in my controller?

Answer (score 18):

The following will allow you to read a raw XML message via a POST to a Web API method:

```
public void PostRawXMLMessage(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
   var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
   xmlDoc.Load(request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);   
}
```

You can debug and inspect the body, headers, etc. and will see the raw XML posted. I used Fiddler's Composer to make a HTTP POST and this works well.

Answer (score 13):

You are sending content type of `text/xml` but you have defined your parameter as `string`. Ideally your XML should be mapped to a **class** so that it can be *deserialised*.

So if you need *raw xml* then it is not supported yet. Web API currently is geared up for serialization MediaTypeFormatters and missing simple type formatters but they can easily built.

This one is a **minimal** implementation of such formatter supporting only read in your case and based on **beta installer** (and not nightly source code since it has substantially changed):

```
public class TextMediaTypeFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
{
    public TextMediaTypeFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml"));
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain"));
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/javascript"));
    }

    protected override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        return type == typeof (string);
    }

    protected override System.Threading.Tasks.Task<object> OnReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream stream, 
        HttpContentHeaders contentHeaders, 
        FormatterContext formatterContext)
    {
        var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        try
        {
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            var s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
            taskCompletionSource.SetResult(s);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            taskCompletionSource.SetException(e);           
        }
        return taskCompletionSource.Task;
    }
}
```

And to use it, just add it to formatters collection:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Insert(0, new TextMediaTypeFormatter());
```

Comment: You can simplify reading the stream with ```var reader = new StreamReader(readStream);var text = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();```

Answer (score 6):

Anyone looking for an updated version of Aliostad's answer above from the beta release to the RC of asp.net mvc 4 web api (minor changes resulted in a slight rework for me).

```
public class TextMediaTypeFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
{

    public TextMediaTypeFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml"));
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain"));
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/javascript"));
    }

    public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        if (type == typeof(String))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        if (type == typeof(String))
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }

    public override Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, System.Net.Http.HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
    {
        var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        try
        {
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            readStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            var s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
            taskCompletionSource.SetResult(s);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            taskCompletionSource.SetException(e);
        }
        return taskCompletionSource.Task;
    }
}
```

Comment: can i talk to you in the chat ?

Answer (score 0):

What solved the issue for me was adding this:

```
static SubscriberController()
{
    //Needed for xml deserialization to work
    var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
    xml.UseXmlSerializer = true;
}
```

(`SubscriberController` is my class which extends `ApiController`, and the above is a static constructor, so it will run once).

Not sure if it also necessary, but I added the `[FromBody]` attribute to my parameter, like so:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SynchronizeImax( [FromBody] SynchronizeRequest synchronizeRequest )
{
    //...
}
```

The great thing about doing it this way is that you can seamlessly handle both XML and JSON input.