# Web API: No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'IEnumerable`1' from content with media type 'text/plain'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I get this error in my client (an ASP.NET MVC application) from a call to my ASP.NET Web API. I checked and the Web API is returning the data alright.

```
No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 
'IEnumerable`1' from content with media type 'text/plain'.
```

I believe that I can inherit from `DataContractSerializer` and implement my own serializer which can attach the `Content-Type` HTTP header as `text/xml`.

But my question is: is that necessary?

Because if it was, it would mean that the default `DataContractSerializer` does not set this essential header. I was wondering if Microsoft could leave such an important thing out. Is there another way out?

**Here's the relevant client side code:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            var response = client.GetAsync("http://localhost:55333/api/bookreview/index").Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                IEnumerable<BookReview> reviews = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<BookReview>>().Result;
                return View(reviews);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", string.Format("Reason: {0}", response.ReasonPhrase));
                return View();
            }
        }
```

**And here's the server side (Web API) code:**

```
public class BookReviewController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<BookReview> Index()
        {
            try
            {
                using (var context = new BookReviewEntities())
                {
                    context.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

                    return context.BookReviews.Include("Book.Author");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage
                {
                    Content = new StringContent("Couldn't retrieve the list of book reviews."),
                    ReasonPhrase = ex.Message.Replace('\n', ' ')
                };

                throw new HttpResponseException(responseMessage);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting your content type for the http request you are making?

Comment: Try switching the return type from IEnumerable to List

Comment: It looks like it is - Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428177/asp-net-mvc4-webapi-and-posting-xml-data

Comment: @justnS  You don't set content-type for GET requests.  Only when you are sending a body i.e. PUT, POST, PATCH.

Answer (score 4):

I believe (because I don't have time to test it now) that you need to explicitly set the Status Code on the responseMessage you are passing to `HttpResponseException`.  Normally, `HttpResponseException` will set the status code for you, but because you are providing a responsemessage explicitly, it will use the status code from that.  By default, `HttpResponseMessage has a status code of 200.

So what is happening is you are getting an error on the server, but still returning a 200.  Which is why your client is trying to deserialize the text/plain body produced by StringContent, as if it were an IEnumerable.

You need to set

```
responseMessage.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
```

in your exception handler on the server.

Answer (score 1):

How about just using `ReadAsStringAsync` if your WebAPI is expecting to return content in plain text?

```
response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: The OP is only expecting a string if the server fails.  I don't think your line above would actually compile.