# How to POST XML content to a WEB API using correct JSON structure?

Tags: xml, json, asp.net-web-api

I am using WEB API to POST the content of a XML file by passing the whole content as a string.
However I am getting error and now I am trying to find out how I should pass this XML string? escape slashes, no double quotes, etc....

Here is a small example of my (incorrect) JSON structure:

```
{"xml":"
<server>
  <networkAdapters>
    <networkAdapter id="3d9c0d9d-d353-4d78-b034-b29f2dd824a0" ipEnabled="true">
      <defaultGateways>
        <defaultGateway address="x.x.x.x" costMetric="20" index="0" />
      </defaultGateways>
      <ipAddresses>
        <ipAddress address="x.x.x.x" subnetMask="255.255.255.192" index="0" />
      </ipAddresses>
      <dnsServers>
        <dnsServer address="x.x.x.x" index="0" />
        <dnsServer address="x.x.x.x" index="1" />
      </dnsServers>
    </networkAdapter>
</server>"}
```

WEB API code:

```
        //POST api/RunningValue_Import
        public object PostRunningValue(param_RunningValue inputData)
        {
            try
            {
                #region Retrieve XML string and Create XDocument
                TextReader tr = new StringReader(inputData.xml);
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(tr);
                #endregion
...
```

I am trying to find out what needs to be done before I POST the whole XML content to my WEB API.

Any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: Why not just pass the XML directly?  Why would you want to embed it into JSON ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428177/asp-net-mvc4-webapi-and-posting-xml-data

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape double quotes in your xml string like so:

```
<dnsServer address=\"x.x.x.x\" index=\"0\" />
```

Also your xml is not well formed, you have not included the closing `</networkAdapters>`
tag.

Comment: well I escaped all double quotes and same problem. Fixed the last tag but that should not matter, I am just passing a long xml STRING; I will only parse it inside the WEB API. Any more suggestions? thank you!

Comment: I think I found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428177/asp-net-mvc4-webapi-and-posting-xml-data

Answer (score 0):

Why not just drop the JSON wrapper and send the XML directly?

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(XElement xElement)
{

...

}
```