# Is this still the right way to read raw XML with ApiController?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin

This [answer from 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14287314/22944) gave me this solution to reading raw XML from a POST:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("raw")]
public HttpResponseMessage ReadRaw(HttpRequestMessage rawRequest)
{
    var requestDocument = XDocument.Parse(rawRequest.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    var request = MyDBContext.GetStuffStaticMethod(requestDocument);
    var responseDocument = request.GetResponseDocument(this._context);
    var xml = responseDocument.ToString();
    return new HttpResponseMessage
    {
        Content = new StringContent(xml, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml")
    };
}
```

Is this still the way to go in the current time frame?

BTW: this was the request from my OWIN-based integration test:

```
using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseUri))
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;

    Func<string, string> callOwin = i =>
    {
        var requestUri = baseUri + i;
        this.TestContext.WriteLine("requestUri: {0}", requestUri);
        response = client.PostAsync(requestUri,
            new StringContent(requestDoc.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting), Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml")).Result;
        this.TestContext.WriteLine("response: {0}", response.ToString());
        return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    };

    var xml = callOwin(path);
    Assert.IsNotNull(response, "The expected response is not here.");
    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode, "The expected response status code is not here.");

    Assert.IsFalse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml), "A response is expected.");
    this.TestContext.WriteLine("xml: {0}", xml);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider [this article from Microsoft evangelist Darrel Miller](http://bizcoder.com/posting-raw-json-to-web-api). He shows us that a combination of `[FromBody]` and `XElement` is the way to go:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("raw")]
public IHttpActionResult ReadRaw([FromBody]XElement rootElement)
{
    var requestDocument = new XDocument(rootElement);
    var request = MyDBContext.GetStuffStaticMethod(requestDocument);
    var responseDocument = request.GetResponseDocument(this._context);
    return this.Ok<XElement>(responseDocument.Root);
}
```